# How to properly use functions from other packages in a R package

Tags: r, namespaces, package

I am a bit confused about this. I have an R package that has a small function (not a mayor part of the package) in which the `principal` function of the `psych` package is called. How do I correctly specify this in DESCRIPTION and NAMESPACE?

Setting `Depends: psych` in DESCRIPTION makes sure the psych package is loaded every time my package is loaded. This works, but it seems redundant for such a small part of my package.

Setting `Suggests: psych` and entering a `require("psych")` in the function is what I do now, however this does not work if `psych` is not installed, and seems to be the wrong way of doing this (writing R extensions says that suggest is meant mainly for examples).

I think I need to import the function. I tried setting `Imports: psych` in DESCRIPTION and `importFrom(psych,"principal")` in NAMESPACE. This works, but on a computer that does not has psych installed it gives an error when loading my package.

Comment: Don't bother, `psych` is a great package, and I'm sure you'll find it useful at some point (it has a lot of helper functions), though you need only one function. Good luck with PCA/FA! =)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The basic question you need to answer is: "do you want the function to be available to all users of the package without further effort?".  If yes, then use imports + the appropriate namespace declarations, if no, then use suggests and print an informative error message if `require("psych")` returns `FALSE`.

I don't understand your import related complaint that: "but on a computer that does not has psych installed it gives an error when loading my package".  This is also true if your package is in depends!

Comment: Thanks, very clarifying and I think suggests is the most appropriate then. I think I made a silly mistake with the import, I thought that only depended packages are installed as well when you install a package from CRAN, but I guess this also happens with imported packages? (tested it only by installing from a zip file)

Comment: Yes, imported packages are automatically downloaded when you install a package.

Comment: So why do we need `importFrom` then? Is it S4 specific?