# Building a package so that it loads other packages automatically in R

Tags: r, package

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to properly use functions from other packages in a R package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5260079/how-to-properly-use-functions-from-other-packages-in-a-r-package)
>   [load data set automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10891146/load-data-set-automatically)

I've built an R package and am now testing it. It requires several packages like scatterplot3d, gdata, etc.

How can I get those packages to load automatically, when someone loads my package?

Thanks!

Edit Re Comments: I've already set imports in the Description and I've set the namespaces file. I know this works because the examples I put in work when I do R CMD Check. However, if I just load up R, type library(mypackage) it gives me an error.

Edit: Solved, I moved the packages I had in the imports section to the depends section. Thank you!

Comment: Read this: http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-exts.html Check out the DESCRIPTION file and in particular the Depends field.

Comment: Read http://stackoverflow.com/a/10951283/602276 to see why it's a bad idea to use `depends` rather than `imports`