# How to import only one function from another package, without loading the entire namespace

Tags: r, namespaces

Suppose I'm developing a package, called `foo`, which would like to use the `description` function from the `memisc` package. I don't want to import the whole `memisc` namespace because :

1. It is bad
2. `memisc` overrides the base `aggregate.formula` function, which breaks several things. For example, `example(aggregate)` would fail miserably.

The package includes the following files :

**DESCRIPTION**

```
Package: foo
Version: 0.0
Title: Foo
Imports:
    memisc
Collate:
    'foo.R'
```

**NAMESPACE**

```
export(bar)
importFrom(memisc,description)
```

**R/foo.R**

```
##' bar function
##'
##' @param x something
##' @return nothing
##' @importFrom memisc description
##' @export

`bar` <- function(x) {
    description(x)
}
```

I'd think that using `importFrom` would not load the entire `memisc` namespace, but only `namespace::description`, but this is not the case. Starting with a vanilla R :

```
R> getS3method("aggregate","formula")
## ... function code ...
## <environment: namespace:stats>
R> library(foo)
R> getS3method("aggregate","formula")
## ... function code ...
## <environment: namespace:memisc>
R> example(aggregate)
## Fails
```

So, do you know how I can import the `description` function from `memisc` without getting `aggregate.formula` in my environment ?

Comment: Call it using `memisc::description`?

Comment: @HongOoi No, this won't work. The `::` man page says that using it will load the entire namespace, I already tested it.

Comment: It will load the namespace, but it shouldn't attach it to the search path. That way, you don't have to deal with other functions being overriden.

Comment: @HongOoi You can try the following in a R vanilla session, and you will still get `aggregate.formula` from `memisc` : `memisc::description ; getS3method("aggregate","formula")`.

Comment: I see what you mean. That's pretty weird.

Comment: I wonder to what degree to actual problem here is simply that the memisc authors should not have masked `aggregate.formula`.

Comment: @joran Totally agree with you. At least, for me, it will be a good reminder, never to override a base function.

Comment: There's no way to load a single function from a namespace (without loading the namespace) because R has no way to know what other functions that function needs.

Comment: Also the whole interaction between namespaces and method registration is pretty awful and confusing.

Comment: I went to try and find documentation about namespaces and method registration and couldn't find any. Did not have the stomach to dive into the (I assume C level) source.

Comment: @hadley Yes, that makes sense, now I understand why R has to load every object from the namespace.

Comment: Somewhat related, but not in context of package development, see this post that as of 3.6 you can selectively load functions: roelpeters.be/load-single-function-r-library Also see solutions offered on this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52939086/9059865 which mentions {import} as a solution. (Again, non-package development contexts for those who stumbled here.)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can't.

If you declare `memisc` in the `Imports:` field, the namespace will be loaded when the package is loaded and the exported objects will be findable by your package. (If you specify it in `Depends:`, the namespace will be loaded and attached to the search path which makes the exported objects findable by any code.)

Part of loading a namespace is registering methods with the generic. (I looked but couldn't find a canonical documentation that says this; I will appeal to the fact that functions are declared as S3 methods in the `NAMESPACE` file as evidence.) The defined methods are kept with the generic and have the visibility of the generic function (or, perhaps, the generic function's namespace).

Typically, a package will define a method either for a generic it creates or for a class it defines. The S3 object system does not have a mechanism for formally defining an S3 class (or what package created the class), but the general idea is that if the package defines functions which return an object with that class attribute (and is the only package that does), that class is that package's class. If either of these two conditions hold, there will not be a problem. If the generic is defined in the package, it can only be found if the package is attached; if the class is defined in the package, objects of that class would only exist (and therefore be dispatched on) if the package is attached and used.

In the `memisc` example, neither holds. The `aggregate` generic is defined in the `stats` package and the `formula` object is also defined in the `stats` package (based on that package defining `as.formula`, `[.formula`, etc.) Since it is neither `memisc`'s generic nor `memisc`'s object, the effects can be seen even (and the method dispatched to) if `memisc` is simply loaded but not attached.

For another example of this problem, but with `reorder.factor`, see [Reordering factor gives different results, depending on which packages are loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10939516/892313).

In general, it is not good practice to add methods to generics for which the package does not control either the object or the generic; doubly so if it overrides a method in a core package; and egregiously so if it is not a backwards compatible function to the existing function in the core packages.

For your example, you may be better off copying the code for `memisc::describe` into your package, although that approach has its own problems and caveats.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the clear and detailed answer, and the advices. As a workaround I think I will just put `memisc` in `Suggests` and load the package with  `require` when needed, as suggested by @hadley here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5260079/how-to-properly-use-functions-from-other-packages-in-a-r-package/5261662#5261662

Answer (score 4):

With the caveat that I'm not too familiar with the R environment and namespaces, nor whether this would work in a package — a workaround I've used in programming is to use `::` to copy the function into my own function.

It may have unknown consequences of loading the whole package, as discussed in the comments to OP's question, but it seems to not attach the package's function names to R namespace and mask existing function names.

Example:
`my_memisc_description <- memisc::description`

Answer (score 3):

Use `include.only`

```r
library(dplyr, include.only = "select")

# So `select` works:
cars |> select(speed) |> head(2)
#>   speed
#> 1     4
#> 2     4

# But other dplyr functions do not: 
cars |> slice(1:5)
#> Error in slice(cars, 1:5): could not find function "slice"
```

See also: `exclude`

Source:
https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/library.html

Comment: Hadn't seen this feature before. It was apparently added in version 3.6.0 released 2019-04-26. I don't know if it also avoids the registering of methods issue.