# How to use a function in Rcmdr package without loading the GUI?

Tags: r, package

I only want to use the `plotMeans` functions in `Rcmdr`, but whenever I load the library the Rcmdr GUI springs up as well. Is there a way not to do this?

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19838360/how-to-import-only-one-function-from-another-package-without-loading-the-entire) indicates that I can't use `plotMeans` without loading `Rcmdr`.

Comment: Try using `RcmdrMisc::plotMeans` (without loading the package ;))

Comment: With or without loading the package?

Comment: Maybe.. with or without. The problem with not loading will erupt when there is a call to another function in an unloaded package.

Comment: @user20650 Thanks! In fact, I can do `library(RcmdrMisc)` and use the `plotMeans` function as normal. If you want to turn your comment into an answer, I'd gladly accept it.

Comment: @Heisenberg; glad its working...please feel free to add it as answer

Answer (score 1):

Per @user20650's suggestion, I can do the following:

```
library(RcmdrMisc)
# Use plotMeans as normal
```