# Import one function in R package (without importFrom)

Tags: r, r-package

I'm writing an R package and I'd like to use one function from another package (`plotKML`). This external package has so many dependencies that I don't want my users to be required to download etc. If I use `importFrom(plotKML, readGPX)` in the NAMESPACE file it will load all of `plotKML` into the namespace and download all dependencies which I don't want.

So the question is: is it appropriate to copy the code for the one function I need (ensuring that all the dependencies in that one function are included)? If so what is appropriate for the attribution/documentation -- do I copy the documentation from the original?

There is a great discussion of this issue in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19838360/how-to-import-only-one-function-from-another-package-without-loading-the-entire) and the answer by Brian Diggs is very helpful. But he ends with "For your example, you may be better off copying the code for memisc::describe into your package, although that approach has its own problems and caveats" so I'm left with some uncertainty about what the problems are and whether it's appropriate from a attribution perspective.

Comment: Does the code for that function run without the dependencies?

Comment: The function depends on some functions in the XML package which I need to import anyway so no problem. Otherwise it does not require functions from any of the other packages listed in imports (nearly 20 packages required!) see [here](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/plotKML/index.html) for the list that plotKML requires.

Comment: I'd assume that most of your users would have installed at least half of the packages from which plotKML imports anyway.

Comment: Questions about attribution might be best resolved by contacting the package author and simply asking. The main downside is probably that you would then be responsible for maintaining a separate, parallel version of that function.

Comment: Responding to Roland -- even if users have half those packages it still requires installation of ~10 additional (RSAGA, pixmap, dismo etc). This is too high a payload in my opinion.

Comment: It looks like [plotKML](http://cran.at.r-project.org/web/packages/plotKML/index.html) uses the GPL-3 license, which means you can include the function in your package, but your package must then also be GPL-3 licensed (I think -- I am not an expert on licenses by a long shot).

Comment: @joran, post as answer (you could add a sentence about GPL-3)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Questions about the appropriate attribution would probably be best resolved by contacting the package author directly. As noted in the comments above, that package appears to use GPL-3, which should mean that you can include the function in your package but your package must then also be GPL-3 licensed. (As always, probably no one here is a lawyer so that's on you to check...)

The primary downside to copying just the function you need is that then you are responsible for maintaining it. This probably also means maintaining it in a way that keeps it in sync with the original version from **plotKML**. Depending on the package, surrounding code and how often it is updated that could be fairly simple or it could be horrible.